# KeyListener in another class, problems adding it to the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

### first class

```
 private void spielfenster() {
        setSize(1280, 720);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("");
        setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        addKeyListener(new Steuerung());  
    }
```

[...]

```
    private void run() {
        while(true){

            if(we.nachRechts == true && we.mariox < (1280 - 38)){
                we.mariox += 4;
                repaint();
            }
            if(we.nachLinks == true && we.mariox > 0){
                we.mariox -= 4;
                repaint();
            }

            try {Thread.sleep(10);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
```

### 2nd class

```
package game;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Steuerung extends KeyAdapter{

    public Werte we = new Werte();  //object, to get access to the global values in   class "Werte"

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent p){
        int keys = p.getKeyCode();
        if(keys == KeyEvent.VK_D){we.nachRechts = true;}
        if(keys == KeyEvent.VK_S ){we.nachLinks  = true;}
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent r){
        int key = r.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D){we.nachRechts = true;}
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S ){we.nachLinks  = true;}

    }
}
```

New Problem: when i put this exact code of the key-listener in the class "Spielfenster"   its working fine. Where is the problem?

2nd problem (bot not really important for me right now, but also good to know): if im creating an "Spielfenster" object in class "Steuerung" the frame opens himself about 10 times per sec. ?!

Thanks in previous! Palm

Comment: 1) For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form. 4) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough!

Comment: 5) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one. 6) `setLayout(null);` Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space.